# Date range issue in sales order grid in Magento2

Tags: magento2.4, filter, order-grid, timezone

[image]

[image]

In the sales order admin grid when we select a date range in Filter option Magento backend Sales -> Orders, it is not sticking to that date, and showing other dates too in the filter... For example, select 7th July and it shows 6th July data too

I found out that it could be the issue of timezone difference in admin we are using America/Los_Angeles and while in the database it is GMT.

Is there any proper solution for such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Magento are you running? This issue was supposedly meant to be fixed in v2.4.3, however, we're running 2.4.3-p1 and the issue still persists:

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403024155917-MDVA-34330-Orders-not-filtered-according-to-admin-timezone